# Dropdown not visible in small rhandsontable

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have a small rhandsontable with dropdown and date columns. When I click on the dropdown, the list doesn't show up while in case of date field, the date picker is opened easily.

The reproducible code is below:

```
if(interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(rhandsontable)
  library(dplyr)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(br(),
                  br(),
                  
                  fluidRow(column(12, rHandsontableOutput("mytable"))))
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$mytable <- renderRHandsontable({
      data <-
        mtcars %>%
        mutate(datecol = Sys.Date()) %>%
        head(2)
      
      rhandsontable(data, strecH = "all") %>%
        hot_col(2, type = "dropdown", source = c(4, 6, 8)) %>%
        hot_col(12, type = "date")
    })
    
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

The simple target is to get the dropdown list in the same way as that of datepicker.

[image]
[image]

However, at the same time if the table is bigger, it shows up:

[image]

I want to replicate the properties of datepicker to the properties of dropdown. Moreover even for the last row, the dropdown should appear below.

Answer (score 0):

Ypu have to set `overflow = "visible"`:

```r
rhandsontable(data, strechH = "all", overflow = "visible") %>%
```

Note also that you mispell `stretchH`.

---

Edit: proof

```r
library(rhandsontable)

rhandsontable(mtcars[1:3, ], strechH = "all", overflow = "visible") %>%
  hot_col(2, type = "dropdown", source = c(4, 6, 8))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know what's happening in my dashboard but as soon as I make overflow = 'visible', it shows an additional horizontal scrollbar. And I am not able to reproduce the issue using the above code. :(

Comment: @VishalSharma Strange, it works for me - see my edit.